# enabling .doc in web.config breaks codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, web-config, .doc

I have a strange issue which I am battling to troubleshoot and cant find much assistance on web searches.

I have a codeigniter website running with MSSQL and IIS. I have recently added a page that allows for the downlaoding of various file types. I added in the extensions i want on my web.config file. examples .zip,.xlsx,.docx etc. these all work fine with the exception of .doc.

web.config:

```
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html|pdf|csv|xlsx|xls|zip|docx" negate="true" />
```

The above works fine, as soon as I add .doc and restart IIS controller stops working with error: `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

web.config:

```
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html|pdf|csv|xlsx|xls|zip|docx|doc" negate="true" />
```

I have tried playing with my mime configuration as per below link but am getting the same errors.
https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-346.html

Any suggestions I can try or an article that will provide clarity, puzzling that only .doc causes an issues, all other files download without any issues.

Thanks in advance as always.

Comment: this is strange... just for clarification - did you try to remove xls and replace it with doc ? I'm asking because the pattern length is 63 chars - if you add doc you have 67 (including the pipe) - maybe the max pattern length is 2^6 ?

Comment: Thanks, I did try this, removed some others and left .doc but it still breaks. I also thought maybe its the string length. but I can put in another 5 or 6 fake file extensions and it works just fine. just the .doc that breaks it, like its a reserved word or something.